# IDEA, Hamcrest and static imports

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hamcrest

My maven project includes

```
186         <dependency>
187             <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
188             <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
189             <version>1.3</version>
190         </dependency>
```

When i type `assertThat` ..

I'd like for IDEA to figure out that the following is needed

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
```

Instead i get this.

[image]

How can this corrected? How can i get IDEA to perform a static import?

Comment: An aside: you probably want to include `<scope>test</scope>` in your dependency declaration for Hamcrest and other testing libraries.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open the parentheses and you will get a prompt for statically importing the method.  IntelliJ won't understand it's a method you're trying to reference until you add the parenthesis.

In other words, type `assertThat(` and then <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Comment: No problem.  The same will obviously go for `equalTo()` and other matchers.